# sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin - what enter into routing.yml?

Tags: symfony1, routes, doctrine, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I installed Symfony, sfDoctrineGuardUser and sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin, but i dont know what i neen enter to routing.yml.

In documentation

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin

is only:

> You can modify URL's for the sfApply
>   module's action. To do that, simply
>   add this options to your app.yml file:

```
all:
  #...
  sfForkedApply:
    #...
    routes:
      apply: /user/new
      reset: /user/password-reset
      resetRequest: /user/reset-request
      resetCancel: /user/reset-cancel
      validate: /user/confirm/:validate
      settings: /user/settings

all:
  #...
  sfForkedApply:
    afterLogin: after_login_route
    after: after_route
  # as a fallback we use old options too:
  sfApplyPlugin:
    afterLogin: after_login_route
    after: after_route
```

but dont write what need enter to routing.yml andi have error:

> The route "after_route" does not
>   exist.

and

> The route "after_login_route" does not
>   exist.

what i must there entered?

Comment: Do these two routes (after_route and after_login_route) currently exist in your routing.yml? These two clearly need to be existing routes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "after_code" to your default index module and append /index. I use welcome/index for example. It redirects the user after the login to that page.